# Creating test data for custom parent object and child object in test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, childrelationship, child-to-parent

I am writing test class where I need to create test data for standard case object  object and parent object for a custom field in case object. When I do the test run it is giving error at the statement where Case object is associated to parent object

Case is linked to BuildingPermit1 with PermitName field.
Please help.

```
private static Contact Contact1;
private static Case Case1;
private static Building_Permit__c  BuildingPermit;

    //create account
    Account1 = new Account();
    Account1.Name = 'Test Company';
    insert Account1;

    //create Contact
   Contact1 = new Contact();
    Contact1.FirstName = 'Testname';
    Contact1.LastName = 'TLname';
    Contact1.Phone = '6667897867';
    Contact1.Email = 'test@gmail.com';


    //create building permit
    Buildingpermit1 = new Building_permit__c();
       Buildingpermit1.permit_name__c = 'testPermit’;
    insert Buildingpermit1;   

   Case1 = new Case();        
   Case1.Origin = 'Phone';
    Case1.Status = 'New';
   Case1.ContactId = mainContact.Id;
   Case1.Subject = 'test subject';
   Case1.Description = 'test desc';
    if (buildingpermit1.Id != null)
  {
  Case1.Buildingpermit1= Buildingpermit1.Id;  //This is the statement where   
                                               //error shows up
  }
    Insert Case1;
```

Comment: There's no need to check if the Id is not null; if it were, your test would have crashed with an exception before that point.

Comment: Yes. I put that when I got dereferencing null object error.I will remove that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the API name for the field:

```
Case1.Permit_Name__c = Buildingpermit1.Id;
```

Comment: You are awesome. I tried all other options except this one. I thought it will be different data type.Thank you very much. It worked. Today evening I need to move a fix to production.